# Where does the name Ori come from?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, etymology

### What is the origin of the name Ori?

There are suggestions that the name [Ori](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ori) may come from the [Origin](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Origin), however, I have not found any proof to support that.

Their name may have some meaning, and given that the Latin (and presumably Ancient) word for *origin* is *origo* or *originis*, it is possible that they are called by the name derived from their religion/belief (in their language, not only in English). In a similar fashion, the *Alterans'* name may be derived from Latin/Ancient word *alter*, which means *the other*, therefore the ones opposed to the Ori.

Both in-universe and out-of-universe answers are welcome. Hallowed are the Ori.

Comment: Hallowed ***are*** the Ori.

Comment: The power and the greatness of the Ori cannot be denied. Those who reject the Path to enlightenment must be destroyed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a [GateWorld interview](https://web.archive.org/web/20061010142208/http://www.gateworld.net/interviews/executive_decisions_part_1.shtml) with executive producers Brad Wright and Robert Cooper:

> **GW:**  Who decided "Ori?" Who decided on that?
>
> **RC:**  Well, "Origin." It's "Origin." The original idea was the origin of the Ancients, and then I looked at the root of "origin." So I thought, the Ori -- they invented the word "Origin," which is the religion that follows the Ori.

So your supposition is basically correct.

Comment: You have my vote because truth is the beginning of the path to Origin. Ex uno disce omnes.

Comment: I remember this from bonus footage as well...

Comment: Brad Wright and Robert Cooper will know the power of the Ori. The flames of ignorance burn without pain. Beware the power or it will consume you before you know.

Comment: "Orior" in Latin means "be born/created" and "proceed/be derived from"